# After i tried to repair ubuntu 16.04, it's showing Grub menu loader

Tags: grub2, menu

Last time i turned on my computer, ubuntu didn't boot completely, and I got a black screen and a terminal! I tried to fix the problem but it didn't work, so I tried to repair it using live usb. After I rebooted the Pc, now it's showing the gnu Grub menu! And I have no idea what to do! Help me please! Thank you!
Repair URL: http://paste2.org/MmsUNXz9

Comment: If option 1 says "Ubuntu" then press Enter, otherwise tell us whats on the menu.

Comment: Grub is bootloader without it u cant boot ubuntu...is it showing something like grub rescue error..or showing menu to choose... provide more details with snapshots

Comment: There is no option, there is a black screen, and all you can do is command typing, it says above" Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions"

Answer (score 0):

From your boot-info-summary:

```
Script `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' contains no commands and will do nothing
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
```

Have you made any changes to the mentioned files?

Check your filesystem from live-USB with `sudo fsck /dev/sda1`

Check your hard-drive from live-USB with [Smartmontools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)

Comment: I didn't make any changes I don't have much experience with Linux, i don't know what to do now! I don't want to lose my saved data on this partition.

Comment: Boot from live-USB and try to copy your data to external drive.